# Putting HTML in a hidden form field in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm having a problem with a template: I'm trying to display a form for changing a value, in which the user enters the current value in a `textarea` and the old value is kept inside a hidden field for auditing purposes. This value is generally some HTML, and when I render the page this HTML in the hidden field seems to get partially rendered: the `value` attribute of my hidden field gets closed by the first quotation marks inside the entered HTML, and the rest of the HTML spews out onto my page. I've tried using the `escape` decorator but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: why do you need to render the old html at all on the front end? THe user could post the new html and the old could be compared/checked/validated on the backend according the value you currently have stored

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, a better solution might be to keep the audit value in a separate model field defined with `editable=False`. You can still perform checks against the value in a form's clean method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SomeForm, self).clean()
    if instance.the_audit_field == cleaned_data['the_editable_field']:
        ...raise a validation error?
```

You can also modify the value of the audit field from within the model's `save` method.

**Secondly**, assuming you must do it the way you are now, let me address the non-escaped value in your template. I assume you're using something like the following:

```
<textarea value="{{ form.the_audit_field.value }}"></textarea>
```

You should instead use the following:

```
<textarea>{{ form.the_audit_field.value }}</textarea>
```

Note, the value goes **inside** the `textarea`, instead of in the `value` attribute of it.

An even better way to do it is to simply allow Django to render the field for you like the following:

```
{{ form.the_audit_field }}
```